# Lightning security on init page load with server-side call

Tags: lightning-aura-components, security, lightning, security-review

I was reading through the Lightning Security documentation [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Lightning_Security) and noticed one of the points for Cross Site Forgery.

> In order to prevent CSRF attacks, do not invoke any server-side controller method that performs a DML operation automatically as the result of a page load. Specifically, do not invoke server-side DML controller method as onInit handlers, or afterRender handlers (if rendering is performed automatically on page load).
>
> The key is that the DML operation not be performed without an event stemming from human interaction, such as a click. CSRF only applies to server-side DML operations, not operations that update client-side component attributes.

What if I do need to do need to invoke some server side method on the onInit handler? Currently, I have something like below:

```
<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.initializeComponent}"/>

({
    initializeComponent: function(component, event, helper) {
        // api request to my external endpoint
        var action = component.get("v.imageApi");
        
        action.setCallback(this, function(response){
           var images = JSON.parse(response.getReturnValue());
           component.set("v.images", images);
        });

        $A.enqueueAction(action, true);
})
```

Would it be more secure if I moved this over to a helper method instead?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If your component's init action invokes an server-side method which queries(i.e Read) records, then you are fine.

*For example :*

```
<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.initializeComponent}"/>
```

**Controller.js**

```
({
    initializeComponent: function(component, event, helper) {
        // api request to my external endpoint
        var action = component.get("c.getContacts");

        action.setCallback(this, function(response){
           var images = JSON.parse(response.getReturnValue());
           component.set("v.images", images);
        });

        $A.enqueueAction(action, true);
})
```

**Apex Controller :**

```
public class LightningCtrl {

   // we are good here
   @AuraEnabled
   public static List<Contact> getCotacts(){
        return [SELECT id,Name FROM Contact]; 
   }
}
```

But if the server-side method invoked during init/afterRender, does an Create/Update/Delete then, you are vulnerable to CSRF attacks.That is what the below line states:

> In order to prevent CSRF attacks, do not invoke any server-side
>   controller method that performs a DML operation automatically as the
>   result of a page load. Specifically, do not invoke server-side DML
>   controller method as onInit handlers, or afterRender handlers (if
>   rendering is performed automatically on page load).

*For example :*

```
public class LightningCtrl {

       @AuraEnabled
       public static List<Contact> getCotacts(){
            App_Visit__c visit = [SELECT Id,Count__c FROM App_Visit__c WHERE Name = 'TestApp'];

            if(visit.isEmpty()){
                visit = new App_Visit__c(Name = 'TestApp');
            }

            visit.Count__c += 1;

            upsert visit; // CLEAR NO...NO...
            return [SELECT id,Name FROM Contact];
       }
    }
```